# Assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast, when creating a first nod using the create node function

Tags: c, queue, warnings, variable-assignment

I can not seem to find the reason why `first = create_nod();` pops the error.

```
struct nod * create_queue() {
    struct nod * first;
    first = create_nod();
    return first;
}

struct nod * create_nod() {
    struct nod * tmp;
    tmp = (struct nod *) malloc(sizeof(struct nod));
    printf("Nume: ");
    scanf("%s", tmp->name);
    tmp->next = NULL;
    return tmp;
};
```

Comment: Please post the complete error message

Answer (score 2):

Without a proper [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) it's hard to do anything but guess, but my guess is that you don't have a function prototype declaration of `create_nod` before you call it. Before the C99 standard, it was allowed for the compiler to deduce (fancy word for guess) function declarations if one called a function that hadn't been declared yet, and the guess was that it would always return `int`.

Because the compiler thinks the undeclared function `create_nod` returns an `int` and you assign that `int` value to a pointer, you get the warning.

The solution is to either move the whole definition of `create_nod` to be before `create_queue`, or at least create a function prototype declaration above `create_queue`.

And the lesson here is that you should *always* declare things before you use them.